# Multpile stdin using subprocess.call in python (for bowtie)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, subprocess

I'm facing an awkward problem using the subprocess.call operator in python for a script.
I have to run a pipeline program (*bowtie*) multiple times and then use the output in different ways. For that purpose, I'm using the subprocess.call.

Problem is that bowtie takes in input 2 files, an index and a text file, and I can't assign both of them to the stdin parameter.

I've tried also to include the path to the index in the args, but of course bowtie does not recognize it as index and give me an error. Sincer this index is always the same, is there a way to avoid this problem?

Here's part of the code i'm working on (very raw):

```
inpath  = "/media/2tbhd/workdata/nanocage_noadapt/zf/fasta/zf_ad_c_r2.fasta"
ind_path = "indexes/zf_gen_topl"
for elem in plist:
        cmd = subprocess.call(["bowtie","-f","-v 3", "--best" "--suppress 6,7" "-p 6"], shell = True, stdin = inpath, ind_path)
```

Comment: How would you invoke `bowtie` from the command line?  You can't assign two files to stdin in any programming language that I know of...

Comment: "but of course bowtie does not recognize it as index and give me an error"- what error message does it give specifically?

Comment: Please try writing a plain shell command calling bowtie the way you want it, and see if it works. If it does work, paste it here and it'll be easier to give you help on how to transform it into a subprocess.call function. If it doesn't work, I can try figuring out what you did wrong with bowtie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about `bowtie`, but it seems to me that your call should be something like:

```
cmd = subprocess.call(['bowtie','-f',inpath,'-v','3', '--best','--suppress','6,7','-p','6',ind_path])
```

Typically, you pass the list of arguments to subprocess exactly as you would have them on the commandline.  If you know what the command line would look like, you can use the wonderful `shlex` module to split the command.  e.g.:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
cmd=subprocess.call(shlex.split("ls -al"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is actually a file (which is what it looks like in your example), not piped data from some other process, I don't think you should be using STDIN in your subprocess.call function at all!
And as far as I know, you can't provide the index through STDIN to normal command-line bowtie - it has to be a file. So that definitely needs to be a normal argument, not from STDIN.

This is how I normally call bowtie from a script (with both the input file and the index as files, no STDIN used):

```
subprocess.call(["bowtie %s %s %s %s"(full_options,indexname,infile,outfile)], 
                shell=True)
```

Where `full_options` is something like `'-f -m1 -v1 --best --tryhard -S --sam-nosq'` and `indexname` is something like `'Chlre4nm_cassette_new_m'` (which is the base name of a set of index filenames of the form Chlre4nm_cassette_new_m.*.ebwt, in the directory given by the shell environmental variable `$BOWTIE_INDEXES`, which is how bowtie detects its index files).

I realize I'm probably using subprocess.call badly and should split my command/options/args into a list like in the other answer - this is old code, but it does work.

Comment: The way you're calling this (I believe) that you don't need to put "bowtie %s..." in a list ... I think subprocess.call will accept a string.  The advantage to splitting the string into a list is that you can remove the dependency on the shell which should be more efficient, and less prone to attack from malicious users...If the script if for your use, (and you're not malicious;), and performance isn't an issue, then what you have is perfectly acceptable in my opinion...

Comment: @mgilson - good to know, thank you! I know this works (it's code I actually use), but I didn't know if there was any reason to split it into a list. One question: what exactly does "remove the dependency on the shell" mean? I'm asking because I'm not sure it's possible to do that for bowtie, since it relies on a $BOWTIE_INDEXES shell variable to find its index files - would it still work if I set shell=False?

Comment: I was under the impression that subprocess actually spawns a new shell (/bin/sh) to execute the command, but the documentation is actually vague on this point...It does, however, say that it does the equivalent of spawning a new shell...  In any event, if the shell variable is set in the environment, that should be inherited by python and by any subprocess that python creates (Unless you use the env keyword...)  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor